# VBA event raise only once (intermittent)

Tags: vba, excel

## Context

My VBA code often replace worksheets inside the Workbook. Therefore I can't use code directly in the worksheet module as it would be eventually deleted in the process.

I use a user-defined class to handle my events (strongly inspired from [Chip Pearson's withevents article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx))

```
Public WithEvents ws As Worksheet


Private Sub ws_Activate()
    If ActiveSheet.Name = FREEBOM_SHEET_NAME Then
        Call FREEBOM_Worksheet_Activate_Handler
    End If  'ActiveSheet.Name = FREEBOM_SHEET_NAME

End Sub

Private Sub ws_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  'MsgBox Target.Parent.Name

  If Target.Parent.Name = FREEBOM_SHEET_NAME Then
      Call FREEBOM_Worksheet_Change_Handler(Target)
  End If 'Target.Parent.Name = FREEBOM_SHEET_NAME

  If Target.Parent.Name = BOM_SHEET_NAME Then
      Call BOM_Worksheet_Change_Handler(Target)
  End If 'Target.Parent.Name = BOM_SHEET_NAME

End Sub
```

The class is being instantiated when the workbook is opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim WSObj_FreeBOM As FreeBOM_CWorkSheetEventHandler
    Dim WSObj_BOM As FreeBOM_CWorkSheetEventHandler

    If Freebom_EventCollection Is Nothing Then
        Set Freebom_EventCollection = New Collection
    End If

    Set WSObj_FreeBOM = New FreeBOM_CWorkSheetEventHandler
    Set WSObj_FreeBOM.ws = Sheets(FREEBOM_SHEET_NAME)

    Set WSObj_BOM = New FreeBOM_CWorkSheetEventHandler
    Set WSObj_BOM.ws = Sheets(BOM_SHEET_NAME)

    Freebom_EventCollection.Add Item:=WSObj_FreeBOM, Key:=Sheets(FREEBOM_SHEET_NAME).Name
    Freebom_EventCollection.Add Item:=WSObj_BOM, Key:=Sheets(BOM_SHEET_NAME).Name
End Sub
```

During my reading on the subject, I saw that linking your object to a public collection (the declaraiton is in another module (an ordinary module - not a Worksheet module and not a Class module).  : `Public Freebom_EventCollection As Collection`  would keep my instance alive even if the execution leaves the scope of the current initianlization function.

## Problem Description

In most scenario, I will get only one ws_change event being raised.  After that, the sheet behave as if there is no event handler in my code.  Nothing is being raised, not just the worksheet events.

I have look at `Application.EnableEvents` but it is always set to `True` after the first run.

Also, when I use the build in `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` function it worked well.

To me it is probably linked to the fact that I use a class and it is not staying alive after the first run.  But then, I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for you time and help in this matter.

Comment: I have copied your code into a workbook and it seems to work, so I'm probably not understanding your problem.  If I activate either of the sheets, the event fires.  And it keeps on firing.  I can't seem to replicate your issue.  Are you deleting the worksheets and then copying new ones in?  If so, then you will have to ensure that your collection is kept up-to-date, which means adding these new worksheets (and removing the old ones).

Comment: Thank you Steveo40.  I actually didn't think abount maintaining the collection as you described.  You just save me a lot of trouble down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to declare a module level Public instance of the Collection in an ordinary module (not a Worksheet module and not a Class module).  You may as well put the code to manage the collection there as well and simply have calls from the event handlers of the worksheet modules.  You may need to re-initialise the collection whenever you delete a sheet as this will probably trigger a re-compile and reset your project, which will terminate your objects.

Once you have the collection in the standard module, you can monitor its life cycle by adding a watch (SHIFT-F9 in VBE). Then you can keep track of exactly what is going on.

Comment: The Collection is declared in a ordinary module.  I change my question to explicitly mentionne this.

Comment: I also follow you recommandation and follow up on the collection lifecycle.  I have found the problem: I had a `End` statement resetting everything.  The collections was destroyed.

I knew it would be somehting stupid.

Comment: Good for you Michel, believe me I know what it feels like, I'm glad you solved it!
Yes, the End statement, which I only recently realised could be used by itself, will kill everything.  I was advised to use it only as a last resort and to use it cautiously :)